# Question on definition of a connection

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

in my exercise we have a connection defined on the trivial bundle $E=M \times \mathbb{R}^N$, $\nabla=d+A$ where $A \in\Omega^1(M, gl_N(\mathbb{R})$. Now we don't have any explanation what $d$ is supposed to be, I assume its somehow the differential operator but I don't know how to interpret it... can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma$ is a section of $E$, and $X$ a vector field on $N$, $\nabla_X\sigma=d\sigma(X)+A(X)$.

Comment: ok, and what exactly is $d \sigma$? $\sigma:M \rightarrow M \times \mathbb{R}^N$ smooth, right?

Comment: it is the differential you can see $\sigma:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: sorry, but how do you see this?

Comment: $\sigma$ is detemined by its second component.

Comment: I mean I see why you can regard $\sigma $ as a function $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ but $N$ is not necessary $n$, is it?

Comment: And can I write $d \sigma(X)=X(\sigma)$ here?